# Where can I find Xubuntu 20.04 LTS public key?

Tags: xubuntu, signature

[This](https://imgur.com/a/rkgILDr) to be spesific, from [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-verify-the-integrity-of-a-linux-distribution-iso-image).

Answer (score 2):

Use the previous command listed in the tutorial:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys D94AA3F0EFE21092
```

When I did, there was a delay of maybe 30 seconds, and the output was different from that in the tutorial because I had a previous version of that key already. But I could understand that there is a valid signature from the output.